# Do .Net Collection Classes Use .Equals() on contained members to evaluate .Contains()?

Tags: .net, collections

The subject pretty much says it all.

Does a collection class use an (overridden) `.Equals()` method to determine if the collection class `.Contains()` an element or not?  Or does it use reference equality or some other method?

I would like the collection class to ignore a single field on contained members when determining if the collection `.Contains()` an element or not.

Comment: It depends. Not all .NET collections even implement Contains.

Please be more specific.

Comment: True.  I am inheriting directly from CollectionBase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx) [articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx), unless your object implements `IEquatable`, Object.Equals is used.

Comment: Nice, Jacob.  Although your answer was short, it was the first one to come in with just enough info.  Thanks for the links.  I was striking out on the broad searches.  +1 and accepted.  Oh yes... and it worked, too.

Answer (score 3):

[`Collection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132407.aspx) uses [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx).  [`List`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) isn't as clear (it says it uses "the default equality comparer, as defined by the object's implementation of the `IEquatable<T>.Equals` method for T", which doesn't explain what happens if it doesn't implement `IEquatable`), but I would suspect it's the same.

That will use the `IEquatable<T>` implementation if the type implements it, or just regular `Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashCode` (which can be overriden).

Answer (score 2):

This is demanding a personal test case. :)

Write a test, construct a list with one mock object, execute .Contains().

Now check the mock object - did .Equals() get called?
What about the hash value?

Comment: What does the documentation say in this case?

Comment: The test case for a CollectionBase revealed that Object.Equals IS called in the contained classed when the container's .Contains() method is called... but only when the collection contains > 1 element (which makes sense).

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload of Contains that takes an IEqualityComparer, so you can roll your own.